# Compile CSS from a WordPress theme.json file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to Compile CSS from a WordPress theme.json string.

I can't find documentation about how WordPress handles the process.

Let's say I input a whole theme.json as a JS or PHP string, how do I output the CSS style rules related to that input?

Answer (score 0):

As WordPress is open-source, you can look directly at how the `WP_Theme_JSON` class handles this process either on [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0cb8475c0d07d23893b1d73d755eda5f12024585/src/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-data.php) or your local installation at `/wp-includes/class-wp-theme-json-data.php`

More technical details about how WordPress implements features and why can be found via the WP Trac tickets, eg. [#56974](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56974) discusses the performance issues around parsing `theme.json`.